# Gitlab-runner: job succeded but no containers

Tags: docker, networking, debian, gitlab-ci-runner

I am not sure to understand what is wrong with this `gitlab-ci.yml`.

```
image: docker

services:
  - docker:dind

stages: 
  - deploy

before_script:
- docker info
- apk update
- apk upgrade
- apk add python python-dev py-pip build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev
- pip install docker-compose


deploy_sandbox:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate
  environment: stage
```

The `deploy_sandbox` job succeed but I don't have any container on this brand new server. I tried to reinstall gitlab-runner, registered it in a different way making sure that it runs with a `stage` but still got the same issue.

### Lead

There is a **Warning** in the beginning of the log

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-fa6cab46-project-14612439-concurrent-0-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.

Health check error:
service "runner-fa6cab46-project-14612439-concurrent-0-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout

Health check container logs:

Service container logs:
level=info msg="Starting up"
level=warning msg="could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found"
level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]"
level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new containerd process" pid=18
level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339 version=v1.2.10 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter" 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs" error="modprobe aufs failed: "ip: can't find device 'aufs'\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\n": exit status 1" 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
level=info msg="skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1 
level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter aufs in metadata plugin" error="modprobe aufs failed: "ip: can't find device 'aufs'\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\n": exit status 1" 
level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" 
level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter" 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1 
level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd-debug.sock" 
level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock" 
level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.042946s" 
level=info msg="Setting the storage driver from the $DOCKER_DRIVER environment variable (overlay2)"
level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: ip: can't find device 'bridge'\nbridge                167936  1 br_netfilter\nstp                    16384  1 bridge\nllc                    16384  2 bridge,stp\nip: can't find device 'br_netfilter'\nbr_netfilter           24576  0 \nbridge                167936  1 br_netfilter\nmodprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory\n, error: exit status 1"
level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.18.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=a872fc2f86 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.3
level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2375"
level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
*********
```

This line might be the reason: `warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: ip: can't find device 'bridge'\nbridge                167936  1 br_netfilter\nstp`. Googleling it, I see that this error is related with the use of **custom networks** but since this is not my case, I am not sure how to fix it nor whether this is the reason for this strange behavior.

### Env

- Debian 10 (4.19.0-6-amd64)
- gitlab-runner 12.3.0

Comment: Looks similar [https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4260](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4260)

Comment: rolling back to `docker:18.09.7-dind` fix the **Warning** but still no sign of the container